# Migrating from Source build to Docker

Tags: node, docker

If I wanted to migrate my Tezos node that was built from source onto a new server that now runs the docker instance, how would I import my identity.json and secret_keys/endorsements? I haven't been able to locate any reasonable file locations through docker. Do I have to redo everything through the CLI commands? Or is there some file path I can put my old files in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You typically mount volumes into docker containers. If you are using the official tezos/tezos image with it's `entrypoint.sh` you want to mount the following directories:

```
volumes:
   - /data/tezos/mainnet/node:/var/run/tezos/node
   - /data/tezos/mainnet/client:/var/run/tezos/client
```

Where the `/data/tezos/mainnet` path is the location of the tezos data on your host (server running docker), and `/var/run/tezos` is the path where the volume get's mounted inside the container.

So, first move your data to some location on the new server, then start the container with that path mounted to it's respective path inside the container